# Insert multiple values into influxdb

Tags: influxdb

I am trying to insert multiple values into InfluxDB using below statement

```
INSERT API_LOGS,REQUEST_ID=asas REQUEST_TYPE=mhello,REQUEST_NAME=updatequery,RESPONSE_TIME=8
```

I get error like `invalid field format` Is there a way to do above?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use double quotes to define string field:

```
> INSERT API_LOGS,REQUEST_ID=asas REQUEST_TYPE="mhello",REQUEST_NAME="updatequery",RESPONSE_TIME=8

> select * from API_LOGS
name: API_LOGS
time                REQUEST_ID REQUEST_NAME REQUEST_TYPE RESPONSE_TIME
----                ---------- ------------ ------------ -------------
1556660295451272895 asas       updatequery  mhello       8
```

Comment: See protocol specification: https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.7/write_protocols/line_protocol_reference/